# What state is a link in when using the browser back button?

Tags: ios, css, button

I have one of those popular ghost buttons with a transparent background and a 3px yellow border. On the hover, focus and active state the background is filled with yellow.

Has experienced that when you click a button and the use the back button in Safari the state of the button seems to be set to active or focus, which means in my case that it has the yellow background even though it is supposed to be transparent when I come back to the first page.

I tried with Safari and iOS 8 on a iPhone 4S.

Comment: The link will most certain be `:visited`, so does your css affects that as well?

Comment: Exactly what i thought too. It's not my code so I have to take a closer look at it to see if it may be some styles related to that which causes the issue.